# Disable tooltip for 0 value in NVD3 multiBarHorizontalChart

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3 for a multiBarHorizontalChart,i need guidance on how to disable tooltip for 0 values.

```
.tooltip(function(key, x, y, e) {
    return '<h3>' + key + ' ' + e.point.label + '</h3>' + '<p>' + y + '</p>';
})
```

This function i am using to display tooltip value.

Comment: just do not return will not work?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I didn't find any non-hacky way to do this.

The not-so-elegant way would be to replace original handler for event `tooltipShow` with the custom one, that will check the value:

```
var originalTooltipHandler = chart.dispatch.on("tooltipShow");
chart.dispatch.on("tooltipShow", function (e) {
    // check whatever you like here
    if (e.value != 0) {
        // and call original handler only when needed
        originalTooltipHandler.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

But this is not enough if your chart is updated (like, you expect `resize` event or allow changing displayed data by clicking on legend, so almost in all cases), because when `chart.update()` is executed, it will restore original `tooltipShow` handler. To workaround that we have to override `chart.update()` too:

```
nv.addGraph(function () {
    chart = nv.models.multiBarHorizontalChart()
        // ... parameters setting here
    // before data was set, `chart.update()` is not available
    d3.select('#chart1 svg')
        .datum(long_short_data)
        .call(chart);
    // now we can override
    filterTooltips(chart, function (e) {
       return e.value !== 0;
    });
    // ...
    return chart;

    function filterTooltips(chart, predicate) {
        var originalUpdate = chart.update;
        chart.update = function () {
            // call to original `update()` will reset filter
            originalUpdate.apply(this, arguments);
            // set custom filter again
            filterTooltips(chart, predicate);
        };

        var originalTooltipHandler = chart.dispatch.on("tooltipShow");
        chart.dispatch.on("tooltipShow", function (e) {
            if (predicate(e)) {
                originalTooltipHandler.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

See [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/heqv3dee/).